# How to split this kind of string?

Tags: php, string

I have this kind of string :

```
$str = "60 (10+50)";
```

I would like to write in output :

```
$str2 = 60<br/>(10+50)";
```

What is te best way to to it ?

explode the string, ou using strpos ?

Thanks!

Comment: `str_replace(' ', '<br/>', $str)` You're only replacing the space with a line-break right?

Comment: Only the first space. That's why I want to identify the position of "("

Comment: You need to make the general format of your input string clearer. Is there always only one space in the string? Are there always parentheses? Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

you can use preg_replace with limit

`$str2 = preg_replace('/[ ]/', '<br/>', $str, 1);`